# Text non in the same line

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I can't put the two elements in the same line and they are in two separate levels.
I would like to recreate, using only HTML and Css, an automatic typewriter effect with variable text.
I am a beginner with HTML and Css so I don't understand much but it would be very nice if someone explained my mistake in detail.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.text_1 {
  animation: text1;
}

.text_2 {
  animation: text2;
}

.text_1, .text_2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(25, end);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.text_1::after, .text_2::after {
  content: "|";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  animation: caret infinite;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
}

@keyframes text2 {
  0%, 50%, 100% {
    width: 0;
  }
  
  60%, 90% {
    width: 6.50em;
  }
}

@keyframes text1 {
  0%, 50%, 100% {
    width: 0;
  }
  10%, 40% {
    width: 8em;
  }
}

@keyframes caret {
  0%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Hi, i'm a <span class="text_1">Graphic Designer</span><span class="text_2">Photographer</span></h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved by adding `display:flex; align-items: baseline;` to `h1`.

> The flexbox items are aligned at the baseline of the cross axis.
>
> By default, the cross axis is vertical. This means the flexbox items
>   will align themselves in order to have the baseline of their text
>   align along a horizontal line.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  display:flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.text_1 {
  animation: text1;
}

.text_2 {
  animation: text2;
}

.text_1, .text_2 {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  animation-duration: 20s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(25, end);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.text_1::after, .text_2::after {
  content: "|";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  animation: caret infinite;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
}

@keyframes text2 {
  0%, 50%, 100% {
    width: 0;
  }
  
  60%, 90% {
    width: 6.50em;
  }
}

@keyframes text1 {
  0%, 50%, 100% {
    width: 0;
  }
  10%, 40% {
    width: 8em;
  }
}

@keyframes caret {
  0%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Hi, i'm a&nbsp;<span class="text_1">Graphic Designer</span><span class="text_2">Photographer</span></h1>
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much! How do I distance the H1 from the span? They are attached to each other

Comment: @HardaChadi just add &nbsp; (1 character space) before texts. I edited